# Evaluating mass of probability for a single point when the distribution is truncated

Tags: probability-distributions

I have a problem with evaluating the probability mass at $K$ for truncated exponential disribution:

$$
F(t)=
\begin{cases}
0,& t<0\\
1-e^{-\lambda t}, & 0\leq t<K\\
1, & t\geq K
\end{cases}
$$

How to find the probability mass at a single point in $K$? In the lecture it is written that it should be $e^{-\lambda K}$. But why?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well you have the mixed density $f(t) = \lambda e^{-\lambda x}\cdot\mathsf 1_{(0,K)}+ (1-e^{-\lambda K})\cdot\delta_K$. But the probability $\mathbb P(X=x)$ is zero when $x\ne K$.

Comment: Just differentiate. Note that this is a mixed distribution.

Comment: @callculus When I'm differentiating $1$ (because it's distribution for $K$), it gives me $0$ what doesn't make sense when I'm looking at answer.

Comment: @Math1000 my question focuses on situation when $t$ is exactly $K$.

Comment: You seem to have switched from $t$ to $x$ in the middle.

Comment: Yes, there was a mistake. Sorry

Comment: There's a point mass at $x=K$.  $\Pr(X\leq K)=1$ but $\lim_{x\to K^-}\Pr(X\leq x)=1-e^{-\lambda K}$  So, $\Pr(X=K)=1-(1-e^{-\lambda K})=e^{-\lambda K}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$P(X=K)=P(X\leq K)-P(X<K)$$

This with $P(X\leq K)=F(K)=1$ and: $$P(X<K)=\lim_{t\uparrow K}P(X\leq t)=\lim_{t\uparrow K}F(t)=1-e^{-\lambda K}$$